# File isn't being written to (FileWriter)

Tags: java, android

So I have this text file called 'arrlog.txt' that I want time data written to.

I have defined a button called 'btnArr' and a time text field called 'etArr'. When I open this in the emulator, it literally doesn't do anything. It doesnt read to the file. It doesn't shout and scream with an error (IOException), it just closes and does nothing. Rather strange as I cant find a place in my program for this application to simply just close.

[image: source code]

[image: manifest]

I think it may not be initialising something correctly, the file path is correct and so the FileWriter should either run the catch or it should find it and write the numbers into the file.

Comment: `the file path is correct` no. your emulator does not know about your computer file system

Comment: Illegible. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: Don't mess up your post, if you are not happy with the answers,  try to improve the question instead... This kind of edit only get moderator attention..

Comment: @TomDunwoody Please read [ask] and try to make a [mcve]. You're being rude here to the people trying to help you by making your question better.

Answer (score 4):

First, when asking for help with programming problems, please post the source code as text, not as a screenshot.

> the file path is correct

No, it is not. Android does not have a `C:` drive. Presumably, your development machine is Windows, and *that* machine has a `C:` drive. But neither your Android device nor your Android emulator is Windows.

You are welcome to write your data to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), though.

Comment: @TomDunwoody: "Hence why I assumed you would realise I wanted it written to external storage" -- I have no idea why you would assume that people would think that `C:` is external storage. If you want to write to external storage on Android, use something like `getExternalFilesDir()` (available on `Context` and subclasses like `Activity`) or various methods on `Environment` (e.g., `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`). Also note that depending on where you are writing on external storage, you may need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.